# How to modify object in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, pug

So I've object:

```
[ RowDataPacket { id: 1, name: 'title', value: 'My title' },
  RowDataPacket { id: 2, name: 'email', value: 'Some email' } ]
```

And I want to modify it like this:

```
[ { title: 'My title' }, { email: 'Some email' } ]
```

I already tried to modify it, by this way:

```
var data = ** First object on top **
var data2 = [];

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  data2.push({[data[i]['name']]: data[i]['value']});
}
```

Everything is good, I'm getting:

```
[ { title: 'My title' }, { email: 'Some email' } ]
```

But on looping in pug, after modification, I'm getting length is undefined.

```
each item in data2
  p
    item.title
  p
    item.email
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You push every item as a separate object. In your loop the item has either a `title` **or** an `email`. Not both.

Comment: Do you always have 2 items in `data` array? If yes why do you need a loop? If no how are you going to handle additional fields?